# Why does checking a variable against multiple values with `OR` only check the first value?

Tags: python

I want to check if a variable has one of multiple values.  I'm confused about why `or` doesn't work in this situation.  I was following a tutorial that gave the example `if (a or b):`, but when I try to do this it only checks the variable against the first value.  What is wrong with my check?

```
name = raw_input('Please type in your name:')

if len(name) < 5:
    print "Your name has fewer than 5 characters"
elif len(name) == 5:
    print "Your name has exactly 5 characters"
    if name == ("Jesse" or "jesse"):
        print "Hey Jesse!"
else:
    print "Your name has greater than 5 characters"
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
("Jesse" or "jesse")
```

The above expression tests whether or not `"Jesse"` evaluates to `True`. If it does, then the expression will return it; otherwise, it will return `"jesse"`.  The expression is equivalent to writing:

```
"Jesse" if "Jesse" else "jesse"
```

Because `"Jesse"` is a non-empty string though, it will *always* evaluate to `True` and thus be returned:

```
>>> bool("Jesse")  # Non-empty strings evaluate to True in Python
True
>>> bool("")  # Empty strings evaluate to False
False
>>>
>>> ("Jesse" or "jesse")
'Jesse'
>>> ("" or "jesse")
'jesse'
>>>
```

This means that the expression:

```
name == ("Jesse" or "jesse")
```

is basically equivalent to writing this:

```
name == "Jesse"
```

---

In order to fix your problem, you can use the [`in` operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange):

```
# Test whether the value of name can be found in the tuple ("Jesse", "jesse")
if name in ("Jesse", "jesse"):
```

Or, you can lowercase the value of `name` with [`str.lower`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) and then compare it to `"jesse"` directly:

```
# This will also handle inputs such as "JeSSe", "jESSE", "JESSE", etc.
if name.lower() == "jesse":
```

Comment: @iCodez : You should add that doing `.lower()` would also cover strings like `'JeSsE'`.

Comment: `name in {"Jesse", "jesse"}` must be a Python 3 thing, as this appears to be a syntax error in Python 2.

Comment: @cdhowie - That code worked in Python 2.7 and Python 3.2.  Basically, it is creating a set containing "Jesse" and "jesse".  Sets run faster with `in` comparisons.  I don't know how it works though with Python releases prior to 2.7.

Comment: @iCodez : Tuples are faster if the elements to be checked are only 2 in number.

Comment: @iCodez Ah, I see. I think the equivalent Python < 2.7 code would be `set(("Jesse", "jesse"))`.

Comment: @SukritKalra - Yea, I suppose on this small of a scale, the differences are kinda nil.  It's just a force of habit. :)  I'll update my post.

Comment: Just do a timeit result, tuples are almost twice as fast. Though it does not really matter.

Comment: `"Jesse"` does not _evaluate to True_. It evaluates to the string "Jesse", which is truthy.

Answer (score 10):

```
if name in ("Jesse", "jesse"):
```

would be the correct way to do it.

Although, if you want to use `or`, the statement would be

```
if name == 'Jesse' or name == 'jesse':
```

---

```
>>> ("Jesse" or "jesse")
'Jesse'
```

evaluates to `'Jesse'`, so you're essentially not testing for `'jesse'` when you do `if name == ("Jesse" or "jesse")`, since it only tests for equality to `'Jesse'` and does not test for `'jesse'`, as you observed.

Comment: Ah thanks now I understand :) this works, though will go with iCodez for my specific situation, thanks for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 6):

If you want case-insensitive comparison, use `lower` or `upper`:

```
if name.lower() == "jesse":
```

Answer (score 6):

The `or` operator returns the first operand if it is true, otherwise the second operand.  So in your case your test is equivalent to `if name == "Jesse"`.

The correct application of `or` would be:

```
if (name == "Jesse") or (name == "jesse"):
```