# Python: If elif statement firing wrong logic.

Tags: python

I am coding a reddit bot in python that answers specific questions.

Here is the code:

```
    if comment.id not in comments_replied_to:
        if comment.author != r.user.me():

            if "First Question" or "first q" in comment.body:
                comment.reply("First Answer")
                comments_replied_to.append(comment.id)
            elif "Second Question" in comment.body:
                comment.reply("Second Answer")
                comments_replied_to.append(comment.id)
```

When I type a comment with:

> First Question

the response is:

> First Answer

When I type in:

> Second Question

the response is:

> First Answer

Why is it only firing the first statement?

Comment: Do `if "First Question" in comment.body or "first q" in comment.body:` ...

Comment: `"First Question" or "first q" in comment.body` doesn't do what you think it does. Please see the linked question for details.

Comment: @L.MacKenzie YES!! Thanks. You were first and quick - please leave a proper reply below and I will accept when I am able to :)

Comment: Also see [Why does `a == b or c or d` always evaluate to True?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-b-or-c-or-d-always-evaluate-to-true) and [Why does checking a variable against multiple values with `OR` only check the first value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212574/why-does-checking-a-variable-against-multiple-values-with-or-only-check-the-fi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if "First Question" or "first q" in comment.body:` is always true because the first part (before the `or`) reads `if "First Question"` and a non-empty string has the boolean value of true.

So, change it to:

```
if "First Question" in comment.body or "first q" in comment.body:
```

Comment: This is a fairly common question. It's a good idea to check for dupes before answering...