# Or keyword inside a print statement in Python?

Tags: python, printing

How does Python decide the output of this ?

```
print([1, 2] or ["hello"])
```

I mean why will always print([2] or ["az"]) output [2] and not ["az"] ?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a duplicate, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212574/) and the dozens of other dups of the same problem all have answers that explain why this expression evaluates to `[1, 2]`.

Answer (score 3):

Since those lists contain elements, they will evaluate to `True` so Python prints whichever `True` literal comes first.

Comment: So why my interpreter returns false on this: " [ ] == False" ?

Comment: @MikeDelta Just because `[]` is falsey doesn't mean it's `== False`. `None`, numeric zero, and empty containers are all falsey, but only zero is equal to False.

Comment: But the way this answer is worded, I can see how you were confused by that…

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you have to understand here. First:

```
x or y
```

If `x` is truthy, it has the value of `x` (without even evaluating `y`, so `23 or launch_nukes()` doesn't launch the nukes).

Otherwise, it has the value of `y`.

Or, as [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) put it:

> The expression `x or y` first evaluates *x*; if *x* is true, its value is returned; otherwise, *y* is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

Notice that it uses the word "true" here, not the value `True`. This is a bit confusing (even more so if you're talking out loud, or typing in ASCII without formatting…), which is why everyone says "truthy".

---

So, what do "truthy" and "falsey" mean?<sup>1</sup>

- "x is truthy" does *not* mean `x == True`, it means `bool(x) == True`.
- "x is falsey" does *not* mean `x == False`, it means `bool(x) == False`.

For all builtin and stdlib types:

- `False` is falsey.
- `None` is falsey.
- Numeric zero values are falsey.
- Empty containers are falsey.
- Everything else is truthy.

Notice that `None` and empty containers are falsey, but they're not equal to `False`.

By convention, third-party types (including types that you define<sup>2</sup>) should follow the same rules. But sometimes there are good reasons not to. (For example, a NumPy array is neither truthy nor falsey.<sup>3</sup>)

This is covered loosely in [the same docs section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> In the context of Boolean operations, and also when expressions are used by control flow statements, the following values are interpreted as false: False, None, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets). All other values are interpreted as true. User-defined objects can customize their truth value by providing a `__bool__()` method.

The exact details for all builtin types are buried in [the standard type hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy), which is where you learn things like whether `bytes` is covered by "strings and containers" (yes) or whether there's anything special about `NotImplemented` (nope, it's truthy).

---

So, let's go through your examples:

```
[1, 2] or ["hello"]
```

Since `[1, 2]` is a non-empty container, it's truthy. So this equals `[1, 2]`.

```
[] or ["hello"]
```

Since `[]` is an empty container, it's falsey. So this equals `["hello"]`.

```
[] == False
```

`[]` may be falsey, but it's not `False`, or even equal to `False`. Only numbers equal other numbers, and `False` is the number 0 in the numeric type `bool`,<sup>4</sup> but `[]` is not a number. So this is `False`.

---

Just be glad you didn't ask about `is`. :)

---

<sub>1. Technically, these terms aren't defined, even though everyone, even the core devs, uses them all the time. The official reference defines things in terms of evaluating to true or false as a boolean, and then explains what that means elsewhere.</sub>

<sub>2. You can control whether your types' values are truthy by defining a [`__bool__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) method—or by defining [`__len__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__). The only things you're allowed to do are return `True`, return `False`, or raise an exception; if you try to return anything different, it raises a `TypeError`. So, everything is either truthy, or falsey, or untestable.</sub>

<sub>3. If you try to check its truthiness, it will raise an exception. That's because NumPy uses boolean arrays widely—e.g., `array([1, 2]) < array([2, 1])` is `array([True, False])`, and you don't want people writing `if array([1, 2]) < array([2, 1]):`, since whatever they're expecting it to do probably doesn't make sense.</sub>

<sub>4. Yes, `bool` is a numeric type—in fact, a subclass of `int`. This is a little weird when you're first learning, but it turns out to be useful more often than it's dangerous, so it's not *just* preserved for historic reasons.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

`x or y [or z or z1 or z2 or ...]` returns the first Truthy element in sequence, or the last Falsey element if all are Falsey.

`x and y [and z and z1 and z2 and ...]` returns the first Falsey element in sequence, or the last Truthy element if all are Truthy.

---

Python has a notion of Truthiness and Falsiness that is separate from `True` and `False`. An empty list is not `False`, but it is *Falsey*. `bool(something_truthy) == True` and `bool(something_falsey) == False`.

Most things are Truthy, so it's easier to list the Falsey things:

- `0` (note that `-1` is Truthy)
- `None`
- Empty collections (`[]`, `{}`, `set()`, `""`, and etc. Note that non-empty collections containing entirely Falsey elements are *still* truthy e.g. `[None, None, None, None]`)
- `False`

Everything else is Truthy.

---

In your example: `[1, 2] or ["hello"] == [1, 2]` because the first element, `[1, 2` is Truthy (the fact that `["hello"]` is also Truthy is irrelevant in this case). Note that `[1, 2] and ["hello"] == ["hello"]`.