# "else" option alternative is ignored in a while loop

Tags: loops, if-statement

This is probably a simple problem that requires a simple answer...but I have been scratching my head why this happens.
It's a problem on the loop that I am testing. Here's the loop:

```
done = False
while done==False:
    checkUser = input("Do you want to continue?\nType Y or y to continue; any other char to quit\nType here: ")
    print(checkUser) # just to check the input

    if checkUser =='Y' or 'y':
        print ('Yes, I want to continue.')
        done = False
        break

    else:
        print('No. I want to quit now.')
        done = True
        sys.exit()
```

When I run this script on PyCharm, I get the outputs below:

```
Do you want to continue?
Type Y or y to continue; any other char to quit
Type here: y
y
Yes, I want to continue

Do you want to continue?
Type Y or y to continue; any other char to quit
Type here: n
n
Yes, I want to continue
```

Question: why is the "else" option ignored?

I tried so many variations like removing `sys.exit()` and so forth, but the loop still behaves the same way.

Comment: dupe of [Why does checking a variable against multiple values with \`OR\` only check the first value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212574/why-does-checking-a-variable-against-multiple-values-with-or-only-check-the-fi) and many more

Answer (score 0):

change the line `if checkUser =='Y' or 'y':` to `if checkUser =='Y' or checkUser == 'y':` code worked as your expectation. `if checkUser =='Y' or 'y':` means check if checkUser is 'Y' or 'y' is true which is true for any input.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to add `break` at the end of the if-condition as the while loop is already controlled by `done` variable. And your if-condition is not written properly such that the machine interprets as:

```
if (checkUser == 'Y') or ('y')
```

so the conditions become:

```
condition_1: checkUser = 'Y'?
condition_2: 'y'?
```

if 'y' will always generate true so the while loop will go forever. You should do:

```
if checkUser == 'Y' or checkUser == 'y'
```

see if it helps you.